# Employee Qualification Infotype 0024

Tags: abap, sap-hr

In transaction `PA30` after you enter a Personnel Number and select Infotype 0024, it will display all the qualifications of that employee (if they have any).

I want to create a report with 3 parameters ('Qualification group', 'Name' , 'Proficency' ) and after the user inserts data, to display all employees that have those skills. If I access table PA0024, it has no entries, so my question is:

In which table (or where) can I find all employees with their qualifications? 
Any other suggestions on how to make this report would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall, some qualifications can be stored in the PD tables.

- Qualifications are objets type 'Q' stored in HRP1000.
- Relations between an employee and its qualifications are stored into HRP1001. The field ADATANR of this relation is the key for an entry in table HRPAD31 (I think) which contains the rating of this employee for this qualification.

Others tables are T77TS (holds the Qualification IDs and text) and T77TP (holds the Qualification Scale IDs and Texts)

There are also function module in the function group "RHPP", such as RHPP_Q_PROFILE_READ (using P objects in the OBJECTS parameter)

Comment: Great answer, now I just need to find out the Proficiency scale for a qualification, so I can figure out if the qualification is a technical skill or a language (I want to make 2 different parameters for them).

Comment: as far as i remember, you can go from object Q to object QK (qualification group), using relation A030 (?) and then you look at the infotype 1033 of the object. This will gives you the scale id, that you can then check against table T77TS & T77TP

Comment: What you are saying is absolutely true, but the problem is that in the HRP1001 table not all Qualifications ( Q objects ) have a QK ( qualification group ) assigned. I have checked the nearest Qualification that has a QK (the nearest to the Qualification I need to use), and that QK fits, but it might just be pure luck.

Comment: Are the Q objects that are not linked with a QK linked to another Q ? as i recall, this was a hierarchy (Q-Q-...-QK)

Comment: Just for info (some people don't know this method), you could create a wegid (exploitation path ?) using transaction ooaw, and then use the FM "RH_STRUC_GET" to get the full hierarchy of the source Q in one internal table. then you search for the QK (or remove non QK entries) and bam you get your qualification group :)

Comment: So, table HRP1033 holds the QK object ID's and Transaction OOQA holds all possible Qualification, but is there a table where I can see all QK names ?

Comment: I would say that HRP1000 would contains a short text (HRP1000 = base object, HRP1001 = objets relations HRP1xxx = additionnal data, depending on the xxx). HRP1002 *may* contains a description

Answer (score 1):

Using the learner as input, you can execute LSO_LEARNER_GET_CPROFILE_C to get the different qualifications.